Selenium webdriver returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET for reachable webpage
I am trying to setup a selenium webscraper in jupyter notebook on Azure Databricks (on a linux cluster). I am able to set up the service, options, and driver without issue. When I use driver.get(url) I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or the connection times out.
Example 1 - dibbs website

If I try driver.get("webpage") the connection times out.

Example 2 - google
2) When I try driver.get("google") I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET immediately.
My guess is that somehow the firewall is blocking a response, but I'm not sure because I first get a status code of 200, then 500 (in regards to example 1).
Screenshots of Output

example 1 actual output:
what selenium debugging output actually looks like

1.1) example 1 desired output
what selenium debugging output should look like

example 2 output:
what selenium debugging output actually looks like

My Code
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


#set logging level to debug for selenium
logger = logging.getLogger('selenium')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s \n')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
if not logger.hasHandlers(): # prevent duplicate handlers
    logger.addHandler(handler)


#set driver and executable paths
driver_executable_path = path
edge_binary_path = path

#set up the Edge WebDriver
service = EdgeService(driver_executable_path)
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.binary_location = edge_binary_path

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)`

#URL of the awards dates page
url = "dibbs website" #example 1
#url = "google" #example 2

#Open the URL
driver.get(url)

#Wait for the consent page to load and click the "OK" button if present
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "butAgree"))
    ).click()
    print("Clicked OK on consent page.")
except Exception as e:
    print("No consent page or failed to click OK button:", e)

Requests - if it helps
I tried using the requests module in an effort to diagnose the issue. Here is the code and output.
import requests

url = "stack overflow"

r = requests.get(url)
r.status_code

requests error output
Can anyone help me diagnose the root cause issue here?
